# Generating a token/uuid every specific amount of time

Tags: javascript, node.js, logic, token, uuid

I am trying to generate access tokens for my application that are refreshed let’s say (every 10 minutes). After that period a new authorisation should be made. (like oAuth)

Although, the point here is to create an UUID and make it last for a specific amount of time?

In my mind this could work by having the actual timestamp and applying a logic on top of that which will be refreshed after a specific amount of time?

Hopefully the question is not too confusing.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.org/package/token

Comment: Brilliant @PeterLyons! thanks so much. definitely inspecting the code to see how to get there! Nowadays there’s a node module for everything. Impressive ;)

Comment: hey @PeterLyons, if you like to add your answer as a question I would happily mark as correct. Just don’t forget to add this code retrieved from the NPM’s source code which is the logic behind the token generation. `var epoch = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000 / timeStepinSeconds); // http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6238`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the purpose of having an answer to the question.
this is just a copy from @PeterLyons comment which nailed the question properly.

Token npm package does all the job with a really simple configuration.

https://www.npmjs.org/package/token